# No output from Multiprocessing.Queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to use Queue to get a variable out of a Process from multiprocessing. I have tried looking up why this isn't working but I cant seem to find what I am doing wrong. Below is a simplified version of what I am trying to do. It still doesn't print anything. Please help.

```
import multiprocessing

q = multiprocessing.Queue()
def test(q):
    q.put(1)

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=test, args=(q,))
p.start()

while not q.empty():
    print(q.get())
```

The above was over simplified. The program's code looks more like the below code. The full version will do template matching against a video stream, using Open-CV2, and send back if it found a match.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def test_process():
    q.put("image recognition results!")

q = mp.Queue()
p_script = mp.Process(target=test_process, args=(q,)) 



def image_recognition():
    global p_script
    if not p_script.is_alive(): 
        p_script = mp.Process(target=test_process, args=(q,))
        p_script.start()
    while not q.empty():
        print(q.get())

#This will be while true, with various breakout conditions
for _ in range(0, 50):
    image_recognition()
```

This seems very jerry-rigged to me, but being fairly new to programming, I haven't figured out a better way to run the image recognition without blocking the GUI events. If there is another route that would be better, I am all ears.

Comment: With that code, the queue is going to be empty when you get to the `while` loop, so the loop is never going to run.  You need to do a blocking read of the queue.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for the response. I removed the while loop and made it blocking but then it hangs. I waited for 10 seconds before stopping the program. Why would it keep hanging? This process should only take a split second to run.

Comment: Is this EXACTLY your code?  Because you have disregarded the advice to put all of the one-time only code inside an `if __name__=="__main__":` block.  Otherwise, each new process that starts will start another new process.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am sorry that I was not specific in my original question. I have updated it with a more detailed explanation of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with `if not p_script.is_alive():`.  If you have a task to do, you send it to a process.  It doesn't matter whether other earlier processes have finished.

Comment: @TimRoberts The process needs to be running over and over, that statement is to prevent it from making more than one of the process at any given time. Without it, it caused my program to make so many of that process that it crashed my program because of running out of memory.

Comment: Then you need to create a multiprocessing `Pool` object.  Let it run 4 at a time, or some other number.  You keep adding processes to the pool, and they run when opening appears.  You know, if you're only running one a time, there's little point in using multiprocessing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you need to use multiprocessing in Python:

```
import multiprocessing

def test(q):
    q.put(1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=test, args=(q,))
    p.start()

    while True:
        print(q.get())
```

Remember that each new process reloads your main file, which runs it again from the beginning.  Anything you do not want repeated need to be in a `__name__` protected block.  This will print the "1" and then wait for more input that's never coming, so you'll need to Ctrl-C it.